# Best SEO way to redirect from all "posts" to home url

Tags: redirect, seo

I'm working on a affilaite site that has a bunch of products on it. User clicks the product, and goes to the site the product is located on.

Here's my dilemma. All products on my site are each under a different wordpress post. I have about 1700 products.

When google indexed "some" of my site so far, just submitted, I didn't think about what would happen if somebody clicks on a link to a "product" through a google search. On my page I have the name of the product, the image of it, the price and then a button to click to head to the site (a CTA button).

So there is no actually other information for the product. So if a product is, for example, a blender. The user would see the name, the image, the price and then click the cta button and be sent to the site. I don't have individually content for each product other then the price and everything. So I have no use for having a single.php page.

Not knowing this, When I clicked on a link that google had index to one of the products, and when i did, it sent me to my site displaying a wierd template with half the stuff missing on my site since i don't have a dedicated single.php page.

What I did was create a single.php page and redirect people to my home page. So if they land on, let's say site.com/category/name-of-product, it will redirect them to site.com where they can go view all my products. Is this the best way to handle this? Sorry newer to wordpress.

**This is what I have in single.php.**

```
<?php /*  
Template Name: Page Redirect
*/ 

header('Location: https://example.com');
exit();

?>
```

Is there a better way to do this? Or is this sufficient enough? Will this be bad for SEO?

Comment: You should use `wp_redirect` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/. It will allow for future development/filters. It also provides status codes.

Answer (score 1):

Google's indexing of a given page is based, in part, on the relevance of the page content to the page title and metadata. By redirecting to a page that is more than likely not relevant to the page you're, pretty much assuring that; your pages will be ranked very low (if at all) and Google could simply not index the pages.

But in all honesty, this isn't really a WordPress question, it might be better suited for a different forum.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I'll ask in the webmasters section. Appreciate it!